# Automatically displaying the name of the variable in the title of the plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder how to automatically display the variable name of the title of the plot with ggplot2. 
 Like in the example below how can I show the names of variables in the main title?

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, main = "Scatter plot of mpg vs wt")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no hidden variable here, you can create a wrappper for qplot to accomplish this:

```
scatter.qplot <- function(x, y, d) {
qplot(get(x),get(y),data=get(d),main=paste("Scatter plot of",x,"vs",y,sep=" "))
}

scatter.qplot("mpg","wt","mtcars")
```

Comment: Or you could pass the dataframe itself and the names of the variables and specify them in `qplot` with `d[,x]`.

Comment: rather than `get()` one might want to use `ggplot()` and `aes_string`